# Divide a sequence into two continuous subarray's one starting from left and other from right such that total sum of both is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

We need not distribute every elements in one of the two subsequence, we can leave elements , but the elements that are taken must form a continuous subarrray starting from the leftmost or rightmost element. The sets can be empty.

For eg

```
Given
1 -1 -1 -1 

The two sets can be
{},{-1,-1,-1 } => -3


Given
-1, -1, -1, -1, 1 ,1, 1,-1

The two sets can be
{-1,-1,-1,-1},{-1} => -5

Given
1, 1, 1, 1, -3, 12, 1, 1, 9

The two sets can be
{},{} => 0
```

How can this be done efficiently?

**Note: We are not concerned with the actual sets but the minimum total.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you compute the cumulative sum from the left. This is *Θ(n)*. Ditto for the cumulative sum from the right. Starting from the right, for each entry *i*, note the index *j*  such that *j > i*, and the cumulative sum *c* for the entries in *j, ..., n* is the lowest. This can also be done in *Θ(n)*. (Note that you just performed three cumulative operations: two cumulative sums, and one cumulative min (on the cumulative sum from the right) - clearly this can be done in linear time.)

So, at this point, at *Θ(n)*, you've performed preprocessing that enables you to answer in constant time the queries: given index *i*:

- What is the cumulative sum on the left of *i*?
- What is the index *j* to the right of *i* that minimizes the cumulative sum from the right down to *j*.

---

Now loop over *i* from the left. For each *i*, find the sum of the two sums: cumulative from the left, and minimum cumulative from the right. Return the lowest sum.

The overall complexity is *Θ(n)*.